# [Symfony][Doctrine]File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a problems with Doctrine on Sf2.7, when I run a command such as "doctrine: schema: update" I get:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException] File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path, however the given path 0 seems to be incorrect!
```

This worked well until I make a drop of a database to recreate it in "clean" after a lot changed entities ...

Here is an excerpt from my config.yml

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            default_connection: default
            connections:
                default:
                    driver:    pdo_mysql
                    dbname:    "%database_name%"
                    host:      "%database_host%"
                    port:      "%database_port%"
                    user:      "%database_user%"
                    password:  "%database_password%"
                    charset:   UTF8
        orm:
            default_entity_manager: default
            entity_managers:
                default:
                    connection: default
                    auto_mapping: true
```

all entities begin with this type of annotations:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usr_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
```

I searched our friend Google, OpenClassRooms and here of course but not found ... someone an idea ?

Comment: You might need to add the configuration for the default entity manager too

Comment: There is an typo here `* @ORM\Table(name="usr_user")*`

Comment: Also, double check you don't have any files under Resources/config/doctrine as they will interfere with the annotations.

Comment: I corrected the typo and I redo my config.yml like sf2.7 doc but the error still remains

Comment: However I have no directory Resources/config/doctrine... This is related to SF2.7 or just a mistake?

Comment: "Doctrine's auto_mapping feature loads annotation configuration from the Entity/ directory of each bundle and looks for other formats (e.g. YAML, XML) in the Resources/config/doctrine directory." ... so its'not a mystake...  ref:http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error when I imported my project to another pc. The solution worked for me is to try clearing configuration cache using php artisan command.

> php artisan config:cache

then try to create or update doctrine schema.

Comment: Please write detail more and add tag

Comment: Well basically laravel configuration cache makes your laravel application works faster. When you run above mentioned command it will cache all your configuration files into a single file. For example in my case when I imported my project into another system all the previously cached configuration of project conflict with new system configuration, So **config:cache** command remove old cache and updated with new configurations.Hope this make sense.Also check out documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching)

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony, you need to clear `var/cache` directory.

It solved problem for me.